How to calculate the stationary distribution of non-homogeneous Markov chains
I am trying to use mathematical tools to analyze a disk faulty simulator (which is not actually a disk, here it is just for ease of understanding). Long ago, disk failures were simply simulated using Poisson distribution, which enabled the modeling of multiple disk failures using homogeneous continuous time Markov chains. Among them, it is assumed that the failure time of all disks follows the same Poisson distribution, and the repair time follows another Poisson distribution.By using the transition rate matrix, it is easy to obtain a stable distribution of failed disk numbers. However, research over a decade ago showed that disk failure modes are closer to two parameter distributions such as the Weibull distribution. Therefore, I want to know how to calculate the stationary distribution of non-homogeneous Markov processes.
The following two images demonstrate the traditional approach. For more details about the models, refer to https://www.ntnu.edu/documents/624876/1277046207/SIS+book+-+chapter+05+-+Introduction+to+Markov+methods/d98c074f-a48e-45b1-a016-668350efbbe7


